# MySQL select RANDOM with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating user suggestion app. The app get query mysql server and brings 10 random users from user_table, user_images

```
user_table ===> id, name, username
user_image ===> id, userid, image_path, image
```

I Got this script from [explainextended.com](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/) which work pretty well, my problem is adding the user_image table to the query

```
                SELECT  id, name, username
                FROM    (
                          SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                                @lim := 10
                          FROM    user_table 
                        ) vars
                STRAIGHT_JOIN
                        (
                          SELECT  r.*,
                                @lim := @lim - 1
                          FROM    user_table r
                          WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                                AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt
                        ) i
```

I will be glad if anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: so add another join ?

Comment: Is there a particular error you need help with? Look into writing JOINs with MySQL queries, or whatever database server you're using, as @Dagon says.

Comment: basically: .. `left join user_image on user_table.id=user_image.userid`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a random order by then a limit ?

`SELECT r.id, r.name, r.username 
 FROM user_table 
 ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 10`

The join with your user_pictures becomes very easy.

**Edit:**

To answer the original question, since the solution above is too slow. You can just inner join the result in the STRAIGHT_JOIN.

`SELECT  r.*, img.*, 
         @lim := @lim - 1
 FROM    user_table r
 LEFT JOIN user_images img ON (r.id = img.userid)
 WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
         AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt`

Comment: because on a large table that is horrendously inefficient - and was not the question anyway

Comment: This is very slow, I have over 1 million users and this take almost 1.2 minutes to execute

Comment: probably should be `img.userid`